# Ubuntu 12.10 Laptop temperature

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature

I'm using a laptop with a dedicated graphics card with Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot.

#### Windows 7 Idle Temperature

The Windows 7 idle temperature for CPU is 51°C average, and GPU is 46-48.5°C.

#### Windows 7 Loading Temperature

When in load, the CPU temperature varies between 55-61°C, and GPU 49-51°C MAX.

#### Ubuntu Idle Temperature

CPU: 54°C
GPU (ATI Radeon, proprietary driver installed): 50°C

#### Ubuntu Load Temperature

CPU: 58-69°C
GPU:53C MAX.

Is it normal?  If not is there any solution? Note that I’m using Jupiter,latest graphics driver, grub tweaks etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu just has a different fan control than Windows. Seems its profile makes the fans go on a little later than in Windows. This would propably mean that your laptop is more silent :-)

You don't have to worry about it because those temperatures are still harmless. Everything under 80°C is fine and even temperatures up to 90 or 100 are OK if this only happens on occasion and not for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

[TLP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tlp&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) may help

be sure look into /etc/default/tlp