# Acer Aspire One 725 Temperature

Tags: acer, temperature, aspire

I just got my AO725 and I have sucessfully installed Xubuntu 12.10. It's all okay except the temperature which is pretty high if I look to some reviews on the web - it's about 70 to 85° C. I don't have any additional drivers installed, because I only installed the system and some programs.

What could be a problem or it's that the normal temperature for netbook like this?

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that AO725 is indeed running hotter with Ubuntu 12.10 as well than Windows 8.
Windows 8 is measured at 45to55° C, Ubuntu at 68to84° C

Are you using Psensor to monitor the temperature? Can you try increasing the PSensor Update interval to 5 seconds and Measure update interval to 5 seconds as well? Would that slightly bring down your CPU temperature?

Some guy here [Ubuntu 12.10 Laptop temperature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210222/ubuntu-12-10-laptop-temperature) seem to have the answer to why ubuntu is hotter.